# android:screenOrientation is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Canary 1 with AGP 8.4.0-alpha02
is showing

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

as deprecated
[image]

It disappears after I add

```
tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi"
```

But I want to know the alternative for this if this property is deprecated.

Comment: Does it give you any info if you hover over the line that's struck out? Or if you click the little light bulb?